# Rotate a UIImageView around a point off screen? (center of uiImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, rotation, quartz-graphics

Hi I have a UIImageView which is part on, part off screen.

I want to rotate the view around a point off screen (the center of the view.)

How do I do this?

```
fullRotationAnimation           = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    fullRotationAnimation.fromValue= [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
    fullRotationAnimation.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2 * M_PI];
    fullRotationAnimation.duration  = 4;
    fullRotationAnimation.repeatCount = 1;
    [self->greyRings.layer addAnimation:fullRotationAnimation forKey:@"360"];
```

I'm using that code at the moment but it just spins it around the center of the screen.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using block animation:

```
- (void)rotateImageView:(UIImageView *)imageView aroundPoint:(CGPoint)point byAngle:(CGFloat)angle {

    CGFloat sinA = sin(angle);
    CGFloat cosA = cos(angle);
    CGFloat x = point.x;
    CGFloat y = point.y;

    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMake(cosA,sinA,-sinA,cosA,x-x*cosA+y*sinA,y-x*sinA-y*cosA);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:4.0 animations:^{
        imageView.transform = transform;
    }];
}
```

Note that angle is in radians, so a full rotation is 2.0*M_PI.

Comment: Awesome thank you, how can I find the center cgpoint of a ui image view?

Comment: Sure.  CGPoint center = myImageView.center;  (inherited from UIView)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to set anchorPoint of CALayer: see [Specifying a Layer’s Geometry](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006082) for more detail.

```
//(0,0) is the left-bottom of your layer bounds
self->greyRings.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
```

I think a negative anchorPoint should also work. So you'd better give your bounds and we can calculate for you.

Comment: The UIImageView is 976 wide by 720 high, and is place in the centre of the screen horizontally and vertically, thanks.